# Apache Camel: multiple transacted routes not running

Tags: spring, transactions, apache-camel

I have a problem with multiple transacted routes. I have define 8 transacted routes, after launch it nothing happened, the routes looks like blocked. I dont have any idea why this happening. But it works if I define 7 routes, not 8. DataSource and TransactionManager beans are well configured. Can anyone explain me why 8 transacted routes don't work?

```
private void defineRoutesToTestMultipleTransactedRoutes() {
    from("timer://Timer1?fixedRate=true&period=10000").transacted().log("hello from tx1");
    from("timer://Timer2?fixedRate=true&period=10000").transacted().log("hello from tx2");
    from("timer://Timer3?fixedRate=true&period=10000").transacted().log("hello from tx3");
    from("timer://Timer4?fixedRate=true&period=10000").transacted().log("hello from tx4");
    from("timer://Timer5?fixedRate=true&period=10000").transacted().log("hello from tx5");
    from("timer://Timer6?fixedRate=true&period=10000").transacted().log("hello from tx6");
    from("timer://Timer7?fixedRate=true&period=10000").transacted().log("hello from tx7");
    from("timer://Timer8?fixedRate=true&period=10000").transacted().log("hello from tx8");
}

private void defineRoutesToHandleExceptions() {
    onException(Exception.class).handled(false).to("direct:handleException");

    from("direct:handleException")
            .transacted("PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW")
            .log("ERROR in ")
            .log("Exception => ${header.CamelExceptionCaught}")
            .log("Headers => ${headers}")
            .log("Body => ${body}")
            .setHeader(Consts.HEADER_OPEXID, simple("${exchange.getExchangeId()}"))
            .setHeader(Consts.HEADER_ERR_MSG, simple("Exception => ${header.CamelExceptionCaught}"))
            .setHeader(Consts.HEADER_BODY, debug ? simple("${body.toString()}") : constant(null))
            .to("sql:insert into ErrorLog(exchangeId, requestBody, errorMsg) " +
                    "values(:#" + Consts.HEADER_OPEXID + ", :#" + Consts.HEADER_BODY + ", :#" + Consts.HEADER_ERR_MSG + ")?dataSource=pgDS")
    ;
}
```

logs:

```
INFO  Route: route1 started and consuming from: Endpoint[direct://handleException]
INFO  Route: route2 started and consuming from: Endpoint[timer://Timer1?fixedRate=true&period=10000]
INFO  Route: route3 started and consuming from: Endpoint[timer://Timer2?fixedRate=true&period=10000]
INFO  Route: route4 started and consuming from: Endpoint[timer://Timer3?fixedRate=true&period=10000]
INFO  Route: route5 started and consuming from: Endpoint[timer://Timer4?fixedRate=true&period=10000]
INFO  Route: route6 started and consuming from: Endpoint[timer://Timer5?fixedRate=true&period=10000]
INFO  Route: route7 started and consuming from: Endpoint[timer://Timer6?fixedRate=true&period=10000]
INFO  Route: route8 started and consuming from: Endpoint[timer://Timer7?fixedRate=true&period=10000]
INFO  Route: route9 started and consuming from: Endpoint[timer://Timer8?fixedRate=true&period=10000]
INFO  Total 9 routes, of which 9 are started.
INFO  Apache Camel 2.17.0.redhat-630187 (CamelContext: setTrainOpCamelContext) started in 0.590 seconds
```

Screanshot of threads from jvisualvm:
[image]

Comment: What is `direct://handleException`? Do you have any global onException block? If so, can you share that?

Comment: @Bedla thaks for your reply. I have updated my question..